# How to fix "MethodNotAllowedHttpException" when I try to make a Post request with body and headers (guzzle)

Tags: php, laravel, post, guzzle

I am trying to make a post on laravel using Guzzle. I already got one post working but that one doesn't have a header that I need. The problem is when I try to include that same header and raw JSON body I always get the error: MethodNotAllowedHttpException. From my understanding this is the post request function with some structural error (just my thinking).

My code is the following:

```
$response = $client->request('POST', $url, [
        'headers' => [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'x-auth-token' => $token,
        ],
        'body' => $body
    ]);
```

The code above is returning the error.

The following code (from a different function with different goals) just doesn't have the 'x-auth-token' header and it is working just fine:

```
$response = $client->request('POST', $url, [
        'headers' => [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        ],
        'body' => $body
    ]);
$token = $response->getHeader('X-Subject-Token')[0];
```

Update: The error that i get is: Expecting to find auth in request body. The server could not comply with the request sin.

Comment: where are you getting the error? how are you calling the function?

Comment: When you wrote the route is it post or get?

Comment: In the route is post.

Comment: i am getting the error on my browser (error 500 I click on it and then it says MethodNotAllowedHttpException) I am calling the function from a component using axios (goes throw a route)

Comment: So is `$url` the same value in both cases, or are they different? Method Not Allowed basically means there is no routing set up for the combination of method and URL.

Comment: they are different but I copied that url from postman like the rest of the params and the post request is working fine on postman